# Environment variables cached in Rails config?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables

This behavior is really confusing me. It seems like the content of my `ENV` or my configuration is cached somewhere. Here's how to reproduce it:

In a fresh app (I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.2.1), edit `application.rb`:

```
$ cat config/application.rb 
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Myapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    config.env_foo = ENV['FOO']
  end
end
```

The configuration item `env_foo` is now `nil`:

```
$ unset FOO  # make sure FOO is unset
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.0.0-p598 :001 > Rails.application.config.env_foo
 => nil
```

Set some environment variables and see what happens:

```
$ export FOO=barbapapa
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.0.0-p598 :001 > Rails.application.config.env_foo
 => nil 
2.0.0-p598 :002 > ENV['FOO']
 => "barbapapa"
```

So the cache item is still `nil` but `ENV` has changed. Even if I change environment to production:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails console
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.0.0-p598 :001 > Rails.application.config.env_foo
 => nil
```

**Where is this configuration cached and how do I make it reflect the new `ENV`?**

Note: I know that there are other ways to configure Rails, but I'm using Heroku so I think using the environment for configuration is encouraged.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) gem is preloading apps by default in the development environment in Rails 4.

To reload your app, simply kill the spring processes for the current project:

```
spring stop
```

Spring doesn't seem to be able to refresh on environment changes, but it does monitor files. If you are using an `.env` file, with [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) for example, you can add it to [`config/spring.rb`](https://github.com/rails/spring#watching-files-and-directories):

```
Spring.watch '.env'
```

Comment: answering your own question at the same minute as the question? :D

Comment: @lutfianasari Yes :) I know it looks funny but it's actually encouraged. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: ah, I see.. I saw others also answer their own question, but you said "you" in the above answer and that made me questioning :D sorry for my useless comment and thanks for the information link :)

Comment: :-) Sometimes I only read answers so I wanted to be consistent. I tried sticking to the generic you to be less confusing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you